# No reaction to Deep-link defined in info.plist

Tags: ios, deep-linking, url-scheme, deeplink

i defined a **deep-link** in **info.plist** like this :

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myapp.customer</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myapp.com</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

but in Safari there's no reaction to  this link and this message shows up :

> Safari cannot open the page because the server can not be found

Everything is checked and i did as tutorials and  still nothing happens!

Answer (score 2):

The `CFBundleURLSchemes` field should be filled with a **scheme**, not a url. Schemes come before the url to tell the browser what action to take. For example, `https://` is a scheme that tells the browser to establish a secure connection. An Apple URI scheme is simply you telling the browser that you want URLs with your custom scheme (i.e. `customScheme://`) to be handled by your app. HTTP and HTTPS are reserved for Safari on iOS. To allow `customScheme://example/path` to open your app. Just change that field to `customScheme`.

If you would like to register normal web URLs to handle your links you will have to integrate [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html). These can be a pain to set up so I recommend using the [Branch iOS SDK](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/). Their deep linking is free and provides more features on top of Universal Links.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this method in AppDelegate.Swift

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {


     if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix(""){
        //Deep linking link should be like this : 'yourAppScheme'
        if(url.host?.contains("page"))!{
            if(url.path.contains("/yourhoststring")){
                // do some work
            }
        }

    }


    //default
    return false
}
```

Your Url scheme should be like this :  **[scheme]://[host]/[path]**

Here is the link for detailed tutorial:
http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Comment: what is host? and what is path? host is URL identifier in info.plist?? @taimoor-Suleman

Comment: Host and path use for filtering. They are not used in info.plist.

Comment: If you have no filtering options then just ignore these.

Comment: if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("my app.com"){
   
     // Do your stuff here.

    }

Comment: let me ask my question in other way : app should be open when : http://myapp.com/{transaction_id} - get searched in Safari ...what should i do?

Comment: Try in safari like this :
myapp.com://2/3
or
my app.com:// etc